# Bad interaction between \usepackage{ulem,tikz} and citations (glossaries and footnotes) in Tufte-Book document class

Tags: glossaries, tufte, ulem

I constructed a figure with Ti*k*Z in a `tufte-book` document class, and I need to use the `ulem` package as follows

```
\documentclass[symmetric,justified,marginals=raggedouter]{tufte-book}
\usepackage{ulem,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,positioning,arrows.meta,shapes,calc}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,calligraphy}

\usepackage{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
\newglossaryentry{latex}
{
name=latex,
description={Is a mark up language specially suited 
for scientific documents}
}

\begin{document}
\Gls{latex}
\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

I'm having problems using the package `ulem`, which has two consequences:

1. the first is that the glossary entries are no longer edited, only the descriptions are edited!
2. the second is that the formatting of the bibliographic references in the page notes has been modified (underlining of the titles of the references).

How to correct these faults? I specify that I write using Overleaf (I do not think I have access to the codes of the `tufte-book` class ...).

Comment: Either don't load `ulem` at all (i.e. make `\usepackage{ulem,tikz}` read `\usepackage{tikz}`) if you don't need it or load it with the `normalem` option (i.e. split `\usepackage{ulem,tikz}` into `\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}\usepackage{tikz}`). If `ulem` is loaded without the `normalem` option it will redefine `\em` and `\emph` to produce underlined text instead of the standard italics. (Nothing in the code you have shown suggests that you *need* to use `ulem`, but of course there may well be some passages of your document that need it.)

Comment: BTW: There is a typo in the MWE `\begin{document]` should be `\begin{document}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment of moewe give the good results. Thanks